# How can we iterate through multiple arrays in C programming?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have some multidimensional arrays, I have to run them inside a loop.
my code looks like this:

```
int naxes1[3] = { 10,20,1};
int naxes2[3] = { 10,20,1};
int naxes3[3] = { 10,20,1};
```

I like to have a array like this

```
int naxes[3] = {naxes1, naxes2, naxes3};
```

so that I can iterate through them like this:

```
for ( i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    fits_get_img_size(names[0],  3, naxes[i],  &status);
}
```

Here, I am using cfitsio library and it takes naxes1,naxes2,naxes3 as three
dimensional arrays.
In simple words, how can we interate through multiple arrays?

Comment: printf("naxes[0][0]= %d\n", naxes[0][0]); //ans = 1348882124 instead of 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of your needs.
As **Joachim Pileborg** pointed out in his answer, you can use an array of pointers.

On the other hand, you can also define at the beginning of the program a bidimensional array with the values you want:

```
#define  N  4
int naxes[N][3] = { {10,20,1}, { 10,20,1}, { 10,20,1}, {1, 2, 3} };

printf("naxes[3][2] == %d\n", naxes[3][2]);
```

Here `N` denotes the number of arrays having 3 elements.
It can be changed to hold the number of elements you need.

Answer (score 3):

You are very close, but you have to remember that e.g. `naxes1` isn't an `int`, but it can be an `int *`.

So instead of having an array of `int`  for the collection, you should have an array of *pointer* to `int`:

```
int *naxes[3] = {naxes1, naxes2, naxes3};
```

This should of course have become very evident if you only *tried* to compile your program. Next time, please try that, and actually *read* the error messages you get (they often contain hints about what you should do) before asking a question.